# Cascade/Linear Combination of Kernel Functions

Tags: machine-learning, kernel, classification, pattern-recognition

I have a question regarding machine learning and specifically kernel functions. Suppose we have a Kernel function, say K(x), and also another distinct one, say K'(x). I want to know is K(K'(x)) a kernel function as well? That is, if one feeds the output of a kernel function to another kernel, what does it mean? does it make sense or not?

Another question is about the expected behavior of linear combination of well-known kernels,such as RBF, polynomial and MLP. Suppose the MLP kernel yields 60% of accuracy in a classification task and RBF yields 85%. Does necessarily the RBF+MLP yield a better accuracy compared to the one resulted by MLP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah, That's true, I'll remove the one in stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question and not a programming question.  It has also been posted [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92801/cascade-combination-of-kernel-functions).